# Android Studio does not resolve androidTestImplementation dependencies in custom project layout

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, ide, dependencies

I have a project which uses a non-standard source folder layout like this:

```
sourceSets {
    androidTest {
        manifest.srcFile "/myproject/androidTest/AndroidManifest.xml"

        java {
            srcDirs = [
                "/myproject/androidTest/java"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Android studio shows the above source folder just fine and also tags it as "androidTest" in the tree. The problem now starts with dependencies like espresso not resolving in any of the tests (class not found in AS) - although they have been properly declared like this:

```
 androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

If I change 'androidTestImplementation' to just 'implementation' Android Studio recovers and is able to resolve the dependencies (but I do not want to add test dependencies to my implementation scope!)

Is this just a bug in Android Studio 3.2.1 or is there a bug in my setup?

Comment: Try doing androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2' with 3.0.2. It works fine for me.

Comment: Are you still getting the error?

Comment: 3.0.2 produces the same error

Comment: Did you figure out a fix? I have the same where all libraries listed under androidTest is inaccessible from the test files.

Comment: still no fix :(

Comment: Any fix? Same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem. And accidentally found solution...

Just use brackets... so in your case it is:

```
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2')
```